# Is deleting files on persistent disk attached to multiple nodes is considering as a write?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

From google doc :
Persistent Disks can be attached to multiple nodes in read-only mode (when not attached to any instance in read-write mode). You can distribute static content across multiple Compute Engine instances without incurring the cost of replicating the storage.

Case: i have 3 compute engine (all of them have own disk attached with php) , each one manage photos upload,
all photos uploaded are transfered to a common persistent disk.
Idea is distribute all photos from this disk.
Now some user want to delete his photo.
Can i delete this photo from my nodes ?

Is deleting files on persistent disk attached to multiple nodes is considering as a write ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, deletion of files requires writing to file system metadata in disk. You can setup nfs if you need read/write access.

- Fabricio.